Does AWS count failed Rekognition API calls and therefore charges for that calls?
I am using some services of AWS rekognition including face liveness, face compare and face detection api. Now sometimes api calls fail for various reasons for example face liveness api fails to connect the server even the device has stable network connection. My question is does AWS charges for the failed api calls also? Thanks.

If your request never reaches the API endpoint on AWS, then AWS will never even know that the request was made. Therefore, there would be no charge.
However, if the request is received and the network failure happens before/during receiving the response, you would be charged because Rekognition performed the actual work even if you didn't fully download the response.

Suppose during a face liveness check, an android device gets connected with face liveness server and then it ask the user to put his/her face in the oval. But the user then click on the cancel icon and the face liveness check failed. Will it consider an api call charge?  Thanks for your time.

No idea! You could experiment and see what happens. Let us know what you discover!

I think aws support will be able to answer this question. Anyways thank you.
